# Does foursquare offer an advanced places API for a fee?

Tags: ios, api, foursquare

I am creating a GPS mobile dating application that utilizes the free foursquare places API for iOS.  I was told by my developer that foursquare offers an enterprise API for a fee.  Is this true?  And if so, does anyone know any information regarding purchasing this API?  Any info is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Foursquare?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special or "enterprise" API, but we'd like to think our standard API is pretty advanced! ;) There are tons of successful apps that have built upon our APIs, and hopefully it'll meet your needs too. Check out https://developer.foursquare.com/ for all the info.

So, all the APIs we currently offer are free. If you want, you can find out more about this kind of thing in our platform policies: https://foursquare.com/legal/api/platformpolicy